# Is $x$ a boundary point of a set $S$

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification

Let $S$ be a set and suppose that $x \notin S$ and $x \in S'$ where $S'$ denotes the set of accumulation points of $S$. We wish to prove that $x$ is a boundary point of $S$.

If $x \in S'$, then every deleted neighborhood $N^*(x;\epsilon) \cap S \neq \varnothing$. But because $x \notin S$, it follows that $x\in \mathbb{R}-S$. Therefore, every neighborhood of $x \in \mathbb{R}-S$ has a nonempty intersection with $\mathbb{R}-S$. Thus, every neighborhood of $x$ has a nonempty intersection with $S$ and $\mathbb{R}-S$, from which we conclude that $x$ must be a boundary point of $S$.

Is this argument valid? Thanks for any valid inputs.

Comment: Your argument is okay.